# BlueSnap marketplace vendors - what's the minimum details so they get paid?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, marketplace, bluesnap

I'm new to the BlueSnap marketplace - I created some vendors, and I read the documentation - I know that you can start off with email and country:

```
{ 
"email": "jane.shopper@bluesnap.com", 
"country": "US"
}
```

but you need more details to make sure the vendor gets paid. I could go for the full details:

```
{
    "email": "vendor@example.com",
    "firstName": "Joe",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "phone": "1-123-456-7890",
    "address": "123 Main Street",
    "city": "Boston",
    "country": "US",
    "state":"MA",
    "zip": "123456",
    "defaultPayoutCurrency": "USD", 
    "vendorPrincipal": {
        "firstName": "Joe",
        "lastName": "Smith",
        "address": "123 Main Street",
        "city": "Boston",
        "country": "US",
        "zip": "123456",
        "dob": "28-09-9999",
        "personalIdentificationNumber": "1234",
           "driverLicenseNumber": "561196411",
        "email": "individual.vendor@bluesnap.com"
    },
    "vendorAgreement": {
        "commissionPercent": 30
    },
    "payoutInfo": [{
        "payoutType": "ACH",
        "baseCurrency": "USD",
        "nameOnAccount": "vendor",
        "bankAccountType": "CHECKING",
        "bankAccountClass": "PERSONAL",
        "bankName": "Leumi",
        "bankId": "12445",
        "country": "US",
        "state":"MA",
        "city": "Juneau",
        "address": "1 bank address",
        "zip": "12345",
        "bankAccountId": "36628822", 
        "minimalPayoutAmount": 50
        }]
    }
```

I want to define the vendor once, and know it's done and that any sales they do they get paid for. On the other hand, I don't enjoy asking for drivers licenses and all kind of additional information if it's not really needed.

What's the minimal set of fields I should put in to know it's taken care of?

Comment: How is this related to programming?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BlueSnap does allow variation in terms of vendor details - but the goal is eventually to get the vendor through risk review and approval to be paid. It's worthwhile mentioning that you don't have to have everything ready right away - you could start off with the country and email, set the account up and get to selling. But the following list is essential if you want to get the vendor to the next step:

- **Vendor level**

  - email
  - country
  - phone
  - name
  - address
  - city
  - zip
- **Vendor principal level**

  - firstName
  - lastName
  - address
  - city
  - country
  - zip
  - dob
  - personalIdentificationNumber
  - email
- if the vendor principal country is the US, add **driverLicense** to the list. Otherwise - add **passportNumber**. You do not need both.
- **Payout info level** you need at least one payout info and it must include the fields:

  - payoutType
  - baseCurrency
  - nameOnAccount
  - bankAccountType
  - bankAccountClass
  - bankName
  - bankId
  - country
  - city
  - address
  - zip
  - bankAccountId

You can add them all in the same initial call, all in one go without going back to the same vendor for any updates:

```
{
"email": "vendor@example.com",
"name": "John Smith",
"phone": "1-123-456-7890",
"address": "123 Main Street",
"city": "Boston",
"country": "US",
"state":"MA",
"zip": "123456", 
"vendorPrincipal": {
    "firstName": "Joe",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "address": "123 Main Street",
    "city": "Boston",
    "country": "US",
    "zip": "123456",
    "dob": "28-09-9999",
    "personalIdentificationNumber": "1234",
    "driverLicenseNumber": "561196411",
    "email": "individual.vendor@bluesnap.com"
},
"payoutInfo": [{
    "payoutType": "ACH",
    "baseCurrency": "USD",
    "nameOnAccount": "vendor",
    "bankAccountType": "CHECKING",
    "bankAccountClass": "PERSONAL",
    "bankName": "Leumi",
    "bankId": "12445",
    "country": "US",
    "state":"MA",
    "city": "Juneau",
    "address": "1 bank address",
    "zip": "12345",
    "bankAccountId": "36628822", 
    }]
}
```

Although they are not needed to get your vendor paid, I would recommend setting a default commission for the vendor in the agreement section - it will save you on time later when you can rely on this value when processing transactions.